# Referencing an object from the view model in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I want to add an object from my viewmodel to a treeview, but I don't want to use a tree view item.

is there a way to do something like this?

```
<TreeView>
    <SomeTag Object="{Binding MyViewModel.MyObject}/>
</TreeView>
```

The problem is that I'm trying to bind to a non-homogenous data structure

```
ClassA
   ClassB
       ClassC (Collection)
          ClassD
          ClassD
          ...
```

I don't want a node for class A
Added a TreeViewItem for ClassB with static Header text.
Added a TreeViewItem for ClassC with static header text, bound ItemsSource to ClassC, and bound DisplayMemberPath set to a Name property.

Bind another control ro TreeView.SelectedItem.
If I click a ClassB or ClassC item, the SelectedItem is a TreeViewItem.
If I click a ClassD item, the SelectedItem is my object.

If trying to consistently get my object.

Comment: DId you add the viewmodel as datacontext of view?

Comment: Yes. I can bind to my objects just fine. The problem is when I bind to TreeView.SelectedValue/Item I get the TreeViewItem, but if I use ItemsSource, the child nodes are the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) Property.

```
<TreeView Tag="{Binding MyObject}" >
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Is there a way to bind the Tag for TreeViewItems created by Binding the ItemsSource?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `TreeViewItem's` property like this:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Ancestortype={x:Type TreeView}},Path=DataContext.anyobjectofViewmodel}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
............
............
</TreeView>
```